# Object array issue

Tags: java, object, token

I wan to know why am I getting a null pointer exception on the line marked below, I am trying to add stuff from a properties table to the object map, so I can insert column information into a JTable dont know if its 100% clear, but any input will be appreciated

```
    public Object getList(){
    dvd.loadList(dvd.dvdInventory);
    Object [][] data = null;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    Iterator<Object> kitr= dvd.dvdInventory.keySet().iterator();
    Iterator<Object> itr = dvd.dvdInventory.values().iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        String key = (String) kitr.next();
        String values = (String) itr.next();
        String[] tokens = values.split(" / ");
        for ( String token : tokens ){
            data[j][i] = token.toString(); <------this line gets null
            i++;                              pointer exception
        }
        i = 0;
        j++;
    }
    return data;        
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Object [][] data = null;
```

The array is null. YOu need to allocate space:

```
Object [][] data = new Object[5][5];
```

or whatever size you want.

Unless you know the size of the row/columns of the array it is better to use a Vector of Vectors for the DefaultTableModel of JTable.

Edit:

To use Vectors you would restructure the code to be something like:

```
Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

while(itr.hasNext())
{
    String key = (String) kitr.next();
    String values = (String) itr.next();
    String[] tokens = values.split(" / ");

    Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();

    for ( String token : tokens ){

        row.add(token.toString());
    }

    data.add(row);
}
```

Comment: @fge Yep, DefaultTableModel still uses a Vector

Comment: @fge, The question (if you read between the lines) is about populating a TableModel for a JTable. The DefaultTableModel only supports Vectors, not Lists. That is why I made that comment.

Comment: I see... Backwards compatibility sometimes goes way too far :/

Comment: for example I wanted to have Object[][] data = {{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"} {...,...,...,...,...}} like so....how do I declare that?, I have five columns and wanted to populate each row with the five values

Comment: another question, so the method return type would be vector? also now I get an error on the column names, so I guess I will have to declare another vector for the column names right?

Comment: Yes the DefaultTableModel needs two Vectors, one for the column names and one for the data.

Answer (score 1):

Null pointer exception is happening because you have initialized your array as null. You need to allocate some memory to your array, right now it is just null as defined here:

```
Object [][] data = null;
```

You should know, what size do you need to for the array that you have. You cannot simply initialize it to any value. If you don't know the size then consider using the collections, which can grow dynamically.

You may consider using List of Arraylist and define it as :

```
List<List<Object>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
```